# Are 16 schools too many for a professor to provide recommendation letters to?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, recommendation-letter

I plan to apply to approximately 16 schools and am wondering whether that's too many for my recommendation letter providers.

It's happened before that a professor of my friend refused to provide all letters for him because they're too many. They refused to send all the LoR and cut it from 10+ to about five finally. It would be a disaster if the LoR provider changes his/her mind in the end. Also, I don't want to bother my professor that much.

I believe my professors are nicer than him, but still don't know what's a suitable amount of required schools.

I'm applying for master programs and the 16 selections are range from *dream* to *match* to *safe*, with about five in each category. I failed last year and thus I chose a safer (and might be a bit unnecessary) plan.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141080/discussion-on-question-by-outsider-are-16-schools-too-many-for-a-professor-to-pr).

Answer (score 53):

As other people have mentioned, the problem with 16 schools is that a professor cannot, either truthfully or operationally, provide customized letters to 16 different schools. **By "customization"** I mean more than changing the name of the school and program. Good letters of rec use professor's familiarity with their field to speak to applicants' specific strengths with regard to the program, or referencing previous students of theirs who attended the program in question.

In honesty, I wouldn't expect to ask a professor to customize a letter for more than two or three schools, plus a generic one for the others. *Maybe* four custom letters if you have worked very closely with them.

You could let them know what your top few choices are, then acknowledge a generic letter can be shared among the rest.

I would also reconsider whether 16 is a necessary amount. In my field, 10 programs would be a lot.

Comment: The discussion about the costs of applications in the US has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103047/discussion-on-answer-by-azor-ahai-are-16-schools-too-many-for-a-professor-to-pro). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/20058) before posting another comment.

Comment: Looking back at my recommendation requests, I get the feeling that the students who apply to the most places seem to be foreign nationals who might have trouble staying in the US unless they can get enrolled.  Getting an appropriate education might not be the only issue driving the application count.

Comment: I can understand this motivation, and am willing to support it through the recommendation process if I'm in a position to do so.

Answer (score 33):

Tell your professor of your plan to apply to 16 schools, and let them decide if it’s too much. They are capable of making their own decisions without you doing that on their behalf. It’s nice of you to worry about the professor’s well-being, but unnecessary, and counterproductive if it ends up undermining your own success.

And as for the professor regretting having to send so many letters, well, yes, I think that’s something that many of us experienced. It’s unconscionable and stupid that the system works that way. But that’s not your fault. If it’s really a lot of schools and a big time sink for the professor, perhaps they can arrange to delegate the task of uploading the letter to a clerical staff member at their department. That’s their concern, not yours.

**Edit:** I see that several of the answers and comments are discussing whether the number of schools you’re applying to is appropriate, not from the point of view of your specific question about the professor’s letter workload, but in the sense of whether it’s generally in your interest to be applying to that number of programs.

It seems to me worth acknowledging that this sort of gratuitous advice has nothing to do with your actual question and was not solicited by you in any way. In particular, there is no need for you to explain the reasoning that led you to that number or what mix of schools you’ll be applying to, either to the people here or to the professor you’re asking for a letter from (although if you want to seek advice about such things, it’s certainly fine to discuss it).

Comment: Not only ask about 16, tell your professor your top four choices.

Comment: If I were the professor I would encourage the student to focus on the top choices and spend their time increasing the application essay quality.

Comment: I think I should make it clear. I'm applying for master programs and the 16 selections are range from *dream* to *match* to *safe*. I've failed last year and thus I chose a safer (and might be a bit unnecessary) plan.

And I meant the professor of my friend refused* to send all the RL and cut it from 10+ to appr. 5 finally. Anyway, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I fully agree with the last two paragraphs (post-edit)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the other answers, I do not think the professor's time spent customizing is an issue.  Customizing a letter does not take that long.  Professors have lots of practice.  Submitting it can take longer due to low quality submission systems.  But writing the first letter is most of the work.

The issue is that only one of these letters is worth submitting:  the one for the place you are going to enroll in.  We don't know which of the sixteen is the right one, but it should be easy to identify several that are the wrong program for you to enroll in.  Ask yourself:  Is it realistic for me to get in?  Is it unlikely that I will get in to a better program?  Is the program able to provide realistic funding?  Is this a place I am willing to live for years?  If the answer to any of these is no, don't apply.

There's no prize for getting into a lot of graduate programs.

Comment: I think I should make it clear. I'm applying for master programs and the 16 selections are range from *dream* to *match* to *safe*. I've failed last year and thus I chose a safer (and might be a bit unnecessary) plan.

Comment: @outsider That's fine.  Two to three schools in each category should be enough.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist actually there is a (small) prize for getting into a lot of graduate programs.  The prize is choice.  If you only get into one program and they offer financial support then you either take it or leave it.  If you get accepted into two programs they are in competition.

Comment: @emory That's mostly not true because it's mostly possible to determine which choice is better before you apply.  Once you have three reasonable offers, there's little benefit to getting more offers.

Comment: Graduate student pay is only negotiable within a narrow range.

Comment: Determining which is *better* doesn't matter if you don't get in in the first place. If you're applying sequentially, then  yes, you can afford to not apply to everything once you have offers, but if there is only one application period, you can't really filter much beforehand. You can reduce the number of "safe" schools, but I see no reason to reduce the number of dream schools (other than the high costs here in the US)

Comment: @Mars There aren't 16 dream schools to apply to.  And since the decisions are correlated, there are diminishing returns on the effort.

Comment: OP mentioned ~5 dream schools, and with the low chance of getting in, there isn't really much diminishing for the return. The only reasons not to apply to all of the dream schools would be application fees and application time. As for the safe schools, consider what the chances are of getting in, consider what your safety threshold is, then apply to enough schools so that your chance of getting into *at least* 1 is above your threshold. The middle tier is a bit different, but I doubt that at 5 schools you actually see much diminishment there either

Comment: @Mars again you assume the probabilities are independent, which is not true.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Unless schools are jointly handling admissions, I don't see why they wouldn't be independent.

Comment: @Mars They all have the same applicant.

Comment: If you start with an assumed probability of entering that accounts for the applicant's grades, etc, then I think that still makes it independent. If your probabilities are just based on enrollment rates, then yes, I suppose it's not independent, as knowing OP was rejected once suggests they'll be rejected by similar schools

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist We would like to believe that they are somewhat correlated b/c as you say it is the same applicant.  However, we are confident that they are not perfectly correlated.  There is as you say a diminishing return.  The applicant has to decide for themselves how many applications to make.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist it is true that graduate student pay is only negotiable within a narrow range.  However, if salary is the most important thing then most graduate students would be better off in the private sector.  Schools can compete with each other on other factors (and if there are no other factors to compete on then the applicant really should not be going to graduate school).

Answer (score 4):

You can ask him, of course. But the problem with asking for too many is that you will get a general letter sent to all, rather than a letter tailored to each given position.

I realize this is hard if all schools have similar deadlines, but if possible you should spread it out over time, with your professor's OK. You can also have a different professor write some of them.

If your professor has any sort of secretarial service then a lot of letters isn't burdensome as long as you are happy with the same general letter going to all schools.

You should also ask yourself whether sixteen schools is really too many to apply to. If you are a marginal student then it might be, but you should also ask for advice about whether some of the applications are just wasted. Your professor can probably help you choose a smaller set of schools without lessening your chances of acceptance. But, work out a plan with your advisor to make your application process effective.

Comment: Just speaking for myself, I would vastly prefer my students not spread the letters out over time. I save the requests to a folder as they come in and then pick an evening and spend two or three hours uploading them all; I'd rather not have more come in after I think I'm done.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if my personal opinion is worth more than anyone else's, but I don't think of 16 schools as too many -- it's just part of how the game works. And I don't have a secretary; are there actually departments that will let professors use secretarial time for this?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Very wealthy departments do have secretaries that help with letters.  Life is different if your endowment is billions of dollars.

Answer (score 1):

> I plan to apply approximately 16 schools and wondering whether they're too many for my recommendation letter providers...It's happened before that a professor of my friend regretted to provide all letters for him because they're too many.

You needn't necessarily require a letter to support each application (unless that's strictly required). You may be able to submit an application that lists referees, whom schools will contact if interested. It's likely you won't be short-listed by all schools and those that don't are less likely to request references.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how long it will take for your professor to write one great recommendation letter for you. Next, consider how much time it might take your professor to produce 16 fantastic recommendation letters for you. Most people will do a fairly awful job if they feel they are being undervalued or asked to serve unreasonable requests.

That you are asking the question should be evidence enough requesting 16 letters is unreasonable. It shows you were raised right.

Comment: Thanks. But the reason I asked is simply that I don't have much information about how the system works and how the professors write RL, given their familiarity with RL. The peers I know often apply 12-20 schools so tbh I doubt that 16 school is a rare decision. The only difference might be whether they assign all selected programs to 1-2 professors or spread them to more providers. Also, I don't expect my professors would and should provide a great RL for EACH of my programs.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm applying for master programs and the 16 selections are range from dream to match to safe, with about five in each category.

Please for simplicities' sake, choose your top one out of each category, and save yourself so much time and stress.

That would be 3 recommendation letters.
If you must, add 1 or 2 backups and have a max of 5 needed letters.

If you need help narrowing down the choices that is understandable, but you really should take the time to determine which schools are the best fit for you and your goals.

Answer (score -1):

This is a foolish proposition.

You need **one** letter as *an academic reference* from a tutor or project supervisor. This testifies to your worthiness as a student - it is not a personal character reference.

The original is hand-signed. You may make 16+ copies of this and send one to each of the graduate schools you are applying to.

You should really be focussing on writing **16 well-composed application letters** wherein you frankly assess your own capabilities and your vision of yourself as a researcher in the graduate school you are applying to, how you see the new school, your research aspirations, your education perspectives and how you see the graduate school's ethos merging with all these.

Comment: Perhaps down voters can comment on why they down vote. This answer could be a very reasonable response for many countries\systems\situations. Would admissions from the same person to different schools need different letters?

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema Having customized LoRs for every grad school presupposes that the professor writing them knows the desirable type/standard of applicant to each. Can it be that professors see themselves as "scouts" for other universities' graduate schools? I sure hope not.